# Hash to sum every value with each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a hash as shown below:

```
hash = {
  "Hulk" => 25,
  "IronMan" => 75,
  "Groot" => 51,
  "Captain America" =>50,
  "Spider Man" => 40,
  "Thor" => 50,
  "Black Panther" => 49
}
```

I need to find a set of superheroes whose value will be 100 when I sum with each other's value, e.g., Captain America + Thor = 100.

I can iterate over a hash with index with:

```
hash.each_with_index { |(key,value),index| ... }
```

with an inner loop comparing each value.

Is there any better and simple way to approach this?

Comment: What is `hash`? Is it any different from `input`?

Comment: @sawa no difference, I just gave different names. Made required corrections

Comment: FYI: finding a matching _pair_ is a variant of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), sometimes referred to as 2SUM (in reference to [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)). It's a quite common interview question and you should find lots of information / solutions / code examples online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is not huge, one might use [`Array#combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
1.upto(input.size).
  flat_map do |i|
    input.to_a.combination(i).select do |arrs|
      arrs.map(&:last).reduce(:+) == 100
    end
  end.
  map(&:to_h)
#⇒ [{"Hulk"=>25, "IronMan"=>75},
#   {"Groot"=>51, "Black Panther"=>49},
#   {"Captain America"=>50, "Thor"=>50}]
```

---

If you are certain there could be only 2 heroes who’s power sums up to `100`, substitute `1.upto(input.size)` loop with hardcoded `2` in the argument to `combination`. In this case it’d be fast enough even for huge inputs.

Comment: Input is not huge, agreed more than 3 superheroes might also result in 100.
Thanks for the Array combination approach.

Comment: BTW the accepted answer won’t work for 3+ heroes summing up to 100.

Comment: I accepted yours too, but unfortunately, I realized later that I can only accept one. 
* Newbie * :D

Comment: True, it won't work, I didn't assume that this could be any combination.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve linear complexity `O(N)` performance wise

**EDIT** I assumed that you are looking for the combinations of 2, which is incorrect, as I understood.

```
input = { 
  "Hulk" => 25,
  "IronMan" => 75,
  "Groot" => 51,
  "Captain America" => 50,
  "Spider Man" => 40,
  "Thor" => 50,
  "Black Panther" => 49
}

# Create inverse lookup map
inverse_input = input.each.with_object(Hash.new([])){ |(k, v), h| h[v] += [k] }
#=> {25=>["Hulk"], 75=>["IronMan"], 51=>["Groot"], 50=>["Captain America", "Thor"], 40=>["Spider Man"], 49=>["Black Panther"]}

input.flat_map do |hero, power| 
  # Get heroes with needed power only
  other_heroes = inverse_input[100 - power]
  # Remove current hero from the list
  other_but_this = other_heroes.reject{ |name| name == hero }
  # Map over remaining heroes 
  # and sort them for later `uniq` filtering
  other_but_this.map { |h| [hero, h].sort }
end.compact.uniq
# compact will remove nils
# uniq will remove duplicates
#=> [["Hulk", "IronMan"], ["Black Panther", "Groot"], ["Captain America", "Thor"]]
```

If the length of the input is small, you could go with a shorter `O(N^2)` solution:

```
input.to_a.
      permutation(2).
      select{|(n1,v1), (n2, v2)| n1 != n2 && v1 + v2 == 100 }.
      map{ |l,r| [l.first, r.first].sort }.
      uniq
#=> [["Hulk", "IronMan"], ["Black Panther", "Groot"], ["Captain America", "Thor"]]
```

Comment: Actually, this solution is indeed better than mine, but I am unable to find the way to extend it to 3+ heroes (without computing combinations.)

Comment: @mudasobwa, your solution is correct and concise, considering the size of the input performance is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution would be:

```
all_options = input.map { |a| input.without(a).map { |b| [a, b] } }.flatten(1).sort.uniq

valid_options = all_options.select { |r| r.sum(&:second) == 100 }
```

Amendment, the first line can be achieved using `input.combination(2)` (oops). This whole problem can be solved using:

```
input.combination(2).select { |r| r.sum(&:second) == 100 }.map(&:to_h)
```

Comment: Looks interesting, having a hard time understanding, can you please walk me through the code? and I haven't come across the method 'without' before. :D

Comment: I believe nobody has come across the method `without`.

Comment: Credit @mudasobwa for reminding me about the .combination function

Comment: @user3548068 - let me know if you'd like me to explain the second answer :)

Comment: No worries. input.combination(2) will provide you with all the possible combinations (as the name suggests). If you need to adjust the functionality where 3 users sum to 100, simply change the 2 constant.

Comment: Once this is done, you filter the options using the select function. r.sum(&:second) is giving the total of the two superheros values, and then comparing it against 100. This will return an array of all options, mapping to_h will convert it back into the original hash format.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
resultArr = []
input.keys.each do |keyName|
  input.each do |inKey, inValue|
    ((resultArr << [keyName, inKey]) if ((input[keyName] + inValue) == 100)) unless (keyName == inKey)
  end
end

result = []
resultArr.each do |resArr| result << resArr.sort end
result.uniq!
puts result
```

Comment: What if three or more heroes sum up to `100`?

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
input["Thor"] + input["Captain America"]
```

The input object you've created is a hash, and the easiest way to get the value out of a hash is to feed in the key it's associated with:

```
hash["key"]
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question was not clear. 
I need all the combination in that hash which results in 100 
Hulk + ironman also gives me 100.

Comment: Slightly more complicated :D Without iterating through and testing the different combinations as you hinted at in your question I don't think it's possible - and looks like I skim read